# Nested groupings MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I have a table of call details and need to compile a summary query based on date grouping.  The trouble is that a single Call ID can have multiple rows, as you see below. Disposition is 1 = Abandoned, 2 = Handled.  RNA = Ring No Answer.

```
Call ID | Disposition | Call Start       | Queue Name | Agent Name | RNA
010001    2             2014-12-03 13:02   Acme_Brick   Joe Schmoe   FALSE
010002    1             2014-12-03 13:36   Anvils_R_Us  Jane Doe     TRUE
010003    2             2014-12-03 14:22   Acme_Brick   Dan Post     TRUE
010003    2             2014-12-03 14:22   Acme_Brick   Joe Schmoe   FALSE
```

```
SET @reportdate = '2014-12-03';
SELECT `Queue Name`,
SUM(CASE WHEN Disposition = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS handled,
COUNT(DISTINCT `Call ID`) AS calls
FROM call_details
WHERE CAST(`Call Start` AS DATE) = @reportdate
GROUP BY `Queue Name`
ORDER BY `Queue Name` ASC;
```

So, the `SUM(CASE WHEN Disposition = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS handled,` is causing me issues.  The first table below is what I am getting.  The second is what it **should** be.

```
Queue Name | Handled | Calls
Acme_Brick   3         2
Anvils_R_Us  0         1

Queue Name | Handled | Calls
Acme_Brick   2         2
Anvils_R_Us  0         1
```

I know the issue sits with the `CASE` on the the Disposition field; I'm just not sure if I have to create an intermediary summary table, or if there is a compound grouping I can complete that will ferret out the multi-row detail calls.  Appreciate the help in advance ;).

Comment: can you give us sqlfiddle ??

Comment: [**SQL Fiddle** (as is)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e369/1).

Answer (score 3):

Use a conditional COUNT(DISTINCT to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT `Queue Name`,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Disposition = 2 THEN `Call ID` END) AS handled,
COUNT(DISTINCT `Call ID`) AS calls
FROM call_details
WHERE CAST(`Call Start` AS DATE) = @reportdate
GROUP BY `Queue Name`
ORDER BY `Queue Name` ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get rid of the duplicates:

```
SELECT `Queue Name`, SUM(Disposition = 2) AS handled, COUNT(*) AS calls
FROM (
    SELECT `Queue Name`, `Call ID`, MAX(Disposition) AS Disposition
    FROM call_details
    WHERE CAST(`Call Start` AS Date) = @reportdate
    GROUP BY `Queue Name`, `Call ID`) AS subq
GROUP BY `Queue Name`
ORDER BY `Queue Name`
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me that if RNA is true, then the disposition should not be counted. I changed the CASE statement to

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Disposition = 2 and RNA = 'FALSE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS handled,
```

and got the [result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e369/20/1) you wanted. But that is based on the limited data set you provided. It may not hold true but depends on how your business rules on how unanswered calls are considered.